# Consider the following relation on $\mathbb{R}$: $x$ ~ $y$ if any only if, $x^2-y^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: solution-verification, equivalence-relations

**1) Prove this is an equivalence relation**

My attempt:

An equivalence relation has to be **reflexive**, **symmetric**, and **transitive**.

**Reflexivity**: For any $x ∈$ set $S$, $(x, x) ∈ R$ (reflexive property)

- $x^2$ - $x^2$  = $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, hence it is reflexive.

**Symmetry**: For any $x, y ∈$ set $S$, if $(x, y) ∈ R$, then $(y, x) ∈ R$ (symmetric property)

- $x^2$ - $y^2$ = $-(y^2-z^2) \in \mathbb{Z}$, hence it is symmetric.

**Transitivity**: For any $x, y, z ∈ S$, if $(x, y) ∈ R$ and $(y, z) ∈ R$, then $(x, z) ∈ R$ (transitive property)

- Let $a, b, c \in R$ such that $x, y \in R$ and $y, z \in R$
- We have that $x^2 - y^2 \in R$ and $y^2 - z^2 \in R$
- Let $x^2 - y^2 = m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y^2 - z^2  = n \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $y^2 - z^2$ = $- z^2 + y^2  = n$
- $((x^2-y^2) = m)$ + $((- z^2 + y^2)  = n)$ = $x^2 - z^2 = m+n \in \mathbb{Z}$, hence it is transitive.

**2)** **Let $C$ be the equivalence class of $0$ and $I$ the closed interval$[5, 6]$ . How many elements are in $C ∩ I$? Explain.**

I have no idea how to approach this...
I think that the equivalence class of $[0]$ = All $\in \mathbb{Z}$ where $x^2 - y^2 = 0$. But I don't know how to show how many elements are there in $I$.

Can someone please provide some assistance?

Comment: What is the relation exactly? I think it should appear in the body of the question. From your proof, it does not seem to match with the title? Did you mean $x^2-y^2 \in {\mathbb Z}$? Or $x^2-y^2=0$?

Comment: Also, $z$ in "symmetry" should be $x$, and in "transitivity", the sentence "Let $a, b, c \in R$ such that $x, y \in R$ and $y, z \in R$" does not make sense (Shouldn't it be "Let $x, y, z \in {\mathbb R}$ such that $(x, y) \in R$ and $(y, z) \in R$"?)

Comment: I think the title is wrong and the relation is meant to be $x \sim y \iff x^2-y^2  \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Sorry I think I don't understand what equivalence class exactly means. I thought [0] meant all combinations of $x^2 - y^2$ where $x^2 - y^2$ = 0

Comment: @RobertShore: Are you sure they don't mean ordered pairs $(x, y)$ such that $x^2-y^2$ is an integer?  That's the way I read it.

Comment: I would assume the equivalence class of $0$ is all the elements $x$ such that $x\sim 0$ so $x^2\in Z$

Comment: I think the comment of @BrianTung below is correct, and $[0] = \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid x^2-0 \in \Bbb Z \}$.

Comment: So the second part is essentially asking for all values of $x^2$ such that $x^2 - 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ in the interval $[5, 6]$?

Comment: The equivalence class of $x$ for a relation $R$ is the set $\{\; y\; |\;  (x,y) \in R \; \}$ (see https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Equivalence_class). Also, if an equivalence class was a set of ordered pair, the intersection $C\cap [5,6]$ would be trivially empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the set of all numbers between  $5$ and $6$ whose squares are integers. The squares are between $25$ and $36$. So the answer is the set of positive square roots of $25, 26,27,28,29, 30,31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** regarding 1: Define the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \; f(x) = x^2 - \lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ (the fractional part of $x62$) and prove that $f(x) = f(y) \; \Longleftrightarrow \; x \sim y$.

Therefore $x \sim 0 \; \Longleftrightarrow \; f(x) = 0$, i.e. $x^2 \in \mathbf{Z}$, i.e. $x = \pm \sqrt{k}$ with some non-negative integer $k$.